# What would be the Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer() in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

In Magento 1 my code is

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
```

How I set this code in Magento 2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Magento\Customer\Model\Session
```

is used in magento 2 to get object of Customer Session.

You can define in **__construct()** of php file,

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    }
```

Now you can get the info using:

```
$customer = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer();
```

Comment: thanks for reply can you tell me please also this code is in magento 1 $sender_name = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name'); how i change also in magento 2

Comment: You can check this link, https://gist.github.com/wsakaren/3a26a61347cbe485677f

Answer (score 3):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$currentCustomer = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session')->getCustomer();
```

---

***Note: I am against of direct loading object with $objectManager, for better impact you can inject it in your constructor. I have just given example how you can achieve it. `***

**Better way**

---

```
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $_customerSession 
) {
    $this->_customerSession=$_customerSession
}
```

Now you can easily get customer by simply

```
$this->_customerSession->getCustomer();
```