# What would be Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote') in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, core-session

In magento 1 my code is,

```
 Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote');
```

How can I change this piece of code in magento 2?

I know I would need to do something like [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155471/what-would-be-the-magegetsingletoncustomer-session-getcustomer-in-magen):

However, what would be `('adminhtml/session_quote')` in magento 2?

Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in Magento 2 similar to Magento 1 by below way,

```
Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote
```

use in class like below way,

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $sessionQuote
) {
    $this->sessionQuote = $sessionQuote;
}
```

Use like below way after use above,

```
$this->sessionQuote->getOrder();
$this->sessionQuote->getQuote();
```